# how prevent ubuntu 18.04 LTS remove apache2 on startup?

Tags: apt, apache2

Today I powered on my computer and in /var/log/apt/history.log I can read

```
Start-Date: 2020-07-27  09:08:26
Commandline: apt -y purge apache2
Purge: apache2:amd64 (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.13)
End-Date: 2020-07-27  09:08:32
```

I have phpmyadmin and other things that depends on apache2 , why ubuntu keeps remove apache2 every time I reboot the computer ? I already removed nginx to avoid that `apt autoremove` removes apache2

also doesn't work

```
apt install apache2
apt-mark manual apache2 
apache2 was already set to manually installed.
```

Responding to myself :

```
apt-mark manual apache2
```

seems that helped

Comment: What's the rest of the log entry? What/who initiated the action? Was it unattended-upgrades?

Comment: /var/log/apt/history.log only print these 4 lines , don't print requested-by ...

Comment: That's funny, *every single entry* in /var/log/apt/history.log shows who it was requested by.  At least on my pc's.  Unless it has `Commandline: ` entries by themselves